# Какой вариант именования более правильный по БЭМу?

Tags: css, бэм

Есть компоненты карточек, которые выглядят таким образом :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Корректен ли такой вариант наименования? Или правильнее писать не CircleCard, а CardCircle? (в проекте нет какого-то базового компонента Card)

Comment: кому как удобно, я бы писал CardCircle, потому что в общем списке это выглядело бы как-то приятнее, вопрос на вкусовщину.

Comment: БЭМ это немного иное чем наименование файлов